# Open Local File using Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, fileopendialog

Is there a way I can open a file in my local computer using javascript whether it is a jpg, doc, or pdf?

I tried all the codes I found in the internet and I got an "Access Denied" or "Permission Denied" error when running it. I think it is also a security issue.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you've answered your own question: it *is* a security issue. Browser implementations of JS sort-of *sandboxes* JS. You can interact with the browser, you can *request* the browser to do certain things (like JS has access to the DOM via an API in browser implementations), but you can't just go ahead and *do* things.
Not only because of security limitations, but also in part because JS, left to its own devices, has no IO capabilities.

So, basically: JS lacks IO capabilities, and browsers don't provide an IO API that allows scripts to access the client's local file-system. And thank Christ for that, if such an API would have been available, browsing the web would be as risky a thing to do as... trying to teach lions to read in a nuclear reactor, while covered in hot-sauce or something...

Answer (score 0):

major browsers block these kind of requests to access local files because of security reasons.